# OpenDJ verify user's password option?

Tags: opendj

I know simply a LDAP bind can do user password verification. But the thing is that an application server usually uses admin user (cn=Directory Manager) to do all CRUD operations.

By a simple bind operation, we have to create a ldap connection binds with that specific user's dn , which is annoying.

As I know ldapcompare is another alternative, but looks like OpenDJ ldapcompare can not compare plain-text-password(OpenDJ userPassword is encrypted).

But from some ldap browser(Apache LDAP Studio), there's a "Vefiry Password" which works very well.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cn=DirectoryManager` from an application server is a security issue, pretty much like running applications as root in the unix world.

Have you tried using the proxyAuth control?
Here are a few relevant links:

- https://marginnotes2.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/opendj-proxy-auth/
- https://idmdude.com/2015/03/28/opendj-and-the-fine-art-of-impersonation/

Comment: Thanks JnRouvignac. I will try the beautiful impersonation.